# #ifeq parser function always branching to false in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have tried the following:

```
{{#ifeq: {{{gene.codingnature}}} | 1 | Yes | No }}
{{#ifeq: {{{gene.codingnature}}} | "1" | Yes | No }}
{{#ifeq: {{{gene.codingnature}}} | 0 | Yes | No }}
{{#ifeq: {{{gene.codingnature}}} | "0" | Yes | No }}
```

`{{{gene.codingnature}}}` is 0. Output is always **No**.

I've tried as well:

```
{{#ifexpr: {{{gene.codingnature}}} = 0 | Yes | No }}
{{#ifexpr: {{{gene.codingnature}}} = 1 | Yes | No }}
Expression error: Unrecognized punctuation character "{". Expression error: Unrecognized punctuation character "{".
```

But, as you see, it falls into an error.

Comment: How do you know it is `0`? Can you show us the template inclusion?

Comment: It is impossible to know from only this information, but `Expression error: Unrecognized punctuation character "{". Expression error: Unrecognized punctuation character "{".` tells us that `{{{gene.codingnature}}}` might not even be define. Print `codingnature>{{{gene.codingnature}}}<codingnature` on the page and see what it gives you!

Comment: I know it is `0` because writing `{{{gene.codingnature}}}` prints `0`...

Comment: Are you sure it is not just the template preview which shows `No`? I've put your template code [here](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anv%C3%A4ndare:Lokal_Profil/Testmall3) and evaluated it with `gene.codingnature=0` [here](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anv%C3%A4ndardiskussion:Lokal_Profil/Testmall3) and the third case gives `Yes`.

Comment: In my case the third case gives `No`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [Help:Parser functions in templates](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Parser_functions_in_templates)
?

If you just want to pass a boolean and avoid worrying about undefined parameters, missing parameters etc., just use

```
{{#if: {{{gene.codingnature|}}} | Yes | No }}
```

Whatever you pass as parameter will make it true: usually people enter "1", "yes", "true" etc. and they don't have to worry which is correct.

If you really want to pass a literal string 1/0 (e.g. because your template is already called many times like that), you need to specify a default value for the parameter (usually "false", otherwise removing the parameter will equal stating true).

```
{{#ifeq: {{{gene.codingnature|0}}} | 1 | Yes | No }}
```

See how it's rendered: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Project:Sandbox&oldid=1636858